# Regex for PO BOX Validation

Tags: javascript

I am using the pattern:

```
var isPOAddress=/^(A\s*\.?\s*)(P\s*\.?\s*)(O\s*.?\s*)(Box+\*)|(Box\s+#?\d+)/gi;
```

My requirement is: the PO Box should not allow number after Box.

E.g. Box123 or Box 123 should not be accepted.

Comment: hi can you give me the 2 3 strings you want to allow with Box ..?

Comment: My requirement is very simple, if I am entering the text as PO Box123 or PO Box 123, the field should not allow me to accept this string.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([Pp](ost)?[\.\s-]*?[Oo](ffice)?)*?[\.\s-]*?[Bb](ox)?[\.\s+-]*?\d+/
```

**Matches:**

PO Box 34

P.O. Box 987,
po Box 34,
p.o. Box 987,
p.o. box 987,
post office box 7897,
po box 89,
p.o.b. 89,
pob 909,
p.o. box 098,
po-box 098,
p.o.-box 898,
PO-Box 098,
p.o box 0909,
pobox 898,
p-o-box 909,
p-o box 89089,
post office box 098,
P.O. Box 909,
PO Box 098,
PO box 89070,
box 122,
Box122,
Box-122

**Does not match:**
ramapo 324

Comment: wrongly matched with any single B

Answer (score 0):

```
 /(?:PO BOX).(\S\D)/i
```

> Wont match PO BOX 1213 , PO BOX121
>
> Will match PO BOX @32 , PO BOX @sas

is that you were looking for? Please it would be better if you provide some test strings

Comment: Should not allow if the string is something like PO BOX123 or PO Box 123.

Comment: its not allowing ..have you checked ?

Comment: It is still allowing, and the pattern which I am using is
var isPOAddress=/^(A\s*\.?\s*)(P\s*\.?\s*)(O\s*.?\s*)(Box+\*)|(Box\s+#?\d+)/gi;

Comment: My requirement is very simple, if I am entering the text as PO Box123 or PO Box 123, the field should not allow me to accept this string.

Comment: then what you want to allow for example..?

Comment: Actual requirement is not to allow any PO Box related string in the address field. So, in case if the filed has any PO Box related text, it should not allow me to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your needs:

http://regexr.com/3cc2q

```
var isPOAddress = /\bP(ost|ostal)?([ \.]*(O|0)(ffice)?)?([ \.]*Box)?\b/i;
```

- fail - **po box**
- fail - **p.o. box**
- fail - **po bo**
- fail - **post office box**
- fail - **P.O. Box**
- fail - **PO. Box**
- fail - **PO Box**
- fail - **POBox**
- fail - **P O Box**
- fail - **P.O Box**
- fail - **PO**
- fail - **Postal Box**
- fail - **Post Office Box**
- pass - **poop box**
- pass - **pony box**

Comment: 11 County Road P - matched
even single P matched